# Format an array as string in Python

Tags: python, irc, bots

I'm making a python irc moderation bot. 
One of its features is report.

For the reason, it is multiple words, so when the bot outputs the report, it appears as

```
Report from aletheia Offender: codefreak Channel: #admin Reason: ['test', 'report']
```

How do I format the reason (written as line[6:] in the code. (6th parameter in the line))
so it appears as one string instead of an array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this gives you what you want:

```
' '.join(['test', 'report'])
```

or in your case possibly:

```
' '.join(line[6:])
```

Comment: will this also work for an array thats 5 words long or 20 words long?

Answer (score 0):

To concatenate this type of strings check the following link.

It will give you answer also by time consume to make the operation and also memory occupied for the same. Check this link: http://www.skymind.com/~ocrow/python_string/

Comment: That article is quite old (it's from 2004). Since then preformance of string concatenation in cPython has greatly improved. I may still be slow as hell in other implementations like jython, a [quick test](http://pastebin.com/06K9pQkQ) shows by how much...